# Filtering a Grouped Table upon a Series of Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, conditional-statements

Let's say I've just carried out this query upon a table to achieve this output:

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT staff_id, tablea_A.item_id, item_type, status, date_installed 
FROM table_A 
INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.item_id = table_B.item_id
Group By staff_id, tablea_A.item_id, item_type, status, date_installed
```

**OUTPUT:**

| staff_id | item_id | item_type | status | date_installed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S4193 | Ball | Active | 17/09/2021 |
| 1 | S5567 | Ball | Active | 22/07/2021 |
| 4 | S9088 | Ball | Reserved | 21/12/2021 |
| 7 | J8877 | Club | Active | 03/03/2016 |

..etc

Now that I've created a table which is grouped primarily by staff_id, I would like to display a single item per staff member, by prioritising this criteria in this order:

a.  balls over any other item

b.  active status over any other status

c.  most recently installed items if date is provided

I've read about using the HAVING clause, but I wouldn't know how to implement it in this sense with a particular criteria. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You don't do any aggregations so it's not clear why you are grouping at all? Maybe look at [MySql top 1 row in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: I want there to be a single item of staff per item primarily but that single person needs to be selected based upon the criteria I identified